# Cheapest way to share ios app with friends and family?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, app-store, testflight

I have created a simple music player app that I would like to share with friends and family and not necessarily on the public app store. What would be the cheapest way to do that? From what I understand, I need to pay for a developer membership in order to use TestFlight, but I worry that if I do that, it still might be refused during app review.

Does anyone have any pointers on not getting refused during app review in order to get it on TestFlight? Or is there another way of doing this? The app is super simple, no login, no ads, no transactions involved. It does involve downloading songs from youtube using an api I did not create (freemium based) and using the phones local storage for the song files. Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way to share except the `TestFlight`. You may have other options by sharing UDID, but this is too many hassles.

Answer (score 1):

You will need at least Apple Developer account and have to pay for that. Once you have the account, you can get the UDID from your friends device and share with them by by distribute ios app using adhocs provision.
More details here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/DistributinganApp/DistributinganApp.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create one ipa file and upload it in diawi.
It will generate one link you can share that link to your family members and through that they can install the app

https://www.diawi.com/

First check the steps how to generate ipa file

Comment: Great thanks! Is there a date limit the user can have the app on their device?

Comment: Yes that link will work for 24 hours only...
If you achieve what you wanted then you can accept the answer

Comment: But you still need a developer membership with this, so why not use TestFlight?

Comment: On the other hand, is this a way to skip the app review process?

Comment: If you want to upload app to appstore then you have to follow the app review process